# Export Collections to BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, firebase-extensions

I have tried to export collection to `BigQuery` using [**Export    Collections to BigQuery**](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-bigquery-export) extension.
  But I am not able to export all collections.

I need to export all collection and subcollection to BiqQuery using **[Export Collections to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-bigquery-export)** extensions

I am able to **export only one** collection but can't export all.

Could anyone please help me to export all collections and subcollections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to export the information to a bucket or a local file by running the command `gcloud firestore export gs://mybucket/my/path` as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/export). This will export all the collections with a single command.

I recommend you to export it to GCS, however, you can load the info to BigQuery by following [one of these methods](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data).

There most likely is an issue with the extension you are using since [extensions are still on beta](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/), but you can still open a [Feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features/) so that they add more functionalities to the extension in the future and/or report any [bug directly](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs/).

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: I already tried export but if I change any firebase collection that value does not change on bigquery.

Comment: I need to if I change any firebase collection that changes automatically update to BigQuey dataset

Comment: Then what you want to do is synchronize them. Currently I do not think there is any solution which would do this automatically, but what you can try to do is create a [Cloud Function with a Firestore Trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) that modifies your Bigquery table similarly to what is being done in [this article.](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/streaming-data-from-cloud-storage-into-bigquery-using-cloud-functions)

Answer (score 1):

You can install a second extension "stream collections to biquery" to have a second collection exported to BQ. Just go to the menu extensions and you did the first time

Answer (score 0):

One thing that was helpful for me was to go to the Cloud Functions section for my Firebase project, hop over to the GCP console side of things, and download a zip of the source code deployed for my `ext-firestore-bigquery-export-fsexportbigquery` function.

In there, I noticed that the value of `process.env.COLLECTION_PATH` ultimately gets passed through to `functions.firestore.document()` which is just constructing a namespaced collection path, where wildcards can be used at *any* level in the path...and therein lies the magic.

If you set your Collection Path to simply be a wildcard variable, such as "{AnyCollection}", then the function will capture events for any and all collections in your Firestore DB. Only one instance of the extension is needed.

Overall solution:

- Set *Collection Path* to "{AnyCollection}"
- Set *Table ID* to something indicating that it's multi collection, such as "AnyCollection"
- It can be helpful to set *Wildcard Column field with Parent Firestore Document IDs* to true, although not required.

  - You also could interrogate the name of the collection out of the `document_name` column in your BigQuery table, which includes paths such as "projects/my-firebase-project/databases/(default)/documents/my-firestore-collection/U5OeEv7jZCY8ja0g2gLr".